# Letter in .org mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, template

.Org mode is very good in writing the outlined text . I use it routinely. But I have to fall back on wordpad or latex when I have to write a letter. Is there any available templates for letter using article class which I can implement within emacs-.org

Comment: You can check https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/koma-letter-export.html for exporting org to koma letter and subsequently generating a pdf.

Comment: There isn't typically a lot of fancy markup or structure in a letter. Org allows you to include arbitrary LaTeX code in your document, so it should be possible to accommodate writing letters without too much effort. Can you provide some specifics about what exactly you want to do?